# Magento 2.2.4 place order exception error "Undefined index: product_id Issue"

Tags: magento2, place-order

I have upgraded Magento with Latest version 2.2.4 and trying to place order.It produce below exception error

> [2018-06-26 12:40:50] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index: product_id in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/StockManagement.php on line 103 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index: product_id in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/StockManagement.php on line 103 at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []

I have checked in file and found that  array variable is producing error

```
$productId = $lockedItemRecord['product_id'];
```

I have tried and changed this with Hard coded then it is working fine.I am not getting what is the issue in this code.

```
$productId = "395";
```

I have already compiled all code and tested in both mode developer and production.

Please support me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

After searching the source of Magento 2.2.4 I found the function in file (vendor\magento\module-catalog-inventory\Model\Configuration.php):

```
public function getDefaultScopeId()
{
    // TODO: should be fixed in MAGETWO-46043
    // "0" is id of admin website, which is used in backed during save entity
    return 0;
}
```

In my case I modify Store parameters at "Stores > All Stores" and my actual store_id/scope_id was 1 and not 0. After changing "return 0" to "return 1", my problem was solved.

As this is anyhow TODO for Magento I expect, that in next upgrade this will be solved and all my modification will be overwritten and everything should work at that time...

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, so now fixed..i have updated the solution in [community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Magento-2-2-show-the-error-in-place-order](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Magento-2-2-show-the-error-in-place-order/m-p/98861/highlight/false#M5634). Pls check the link. Also thumps up.